# How to get the package name where error is triggered in Oracle Forms 6i

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I'm giving support on some oracle forms 6i forms, and I'm getting a Numeric or value error. However, the process is very long and it navigates along many packages in the form. What I could do, is just put messages along the process (only visible to me, of course) to see where exactly it comes out, but this would be really long. So, I was wondering if there is anything I could use like `DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_backtrace` but on the client side, and get the package name where the error was generated. I currently use:

`exception when others then functionThatPrintsMe(sqlerrm);`

But this does not give me enough information.

Comment: What does `functionThatPrintsMe` do?  Could you simply re-raise the exception if you can't resolve the exception so that you can get a full stack trace?  Or even eliminate the exception handler if it's not doing anything to resolve the exception.

Comment: @JustinCave Hi, it just puts a message in a field of the form container (the main window of the application) and sets that field visible.

Answer (score 1):

DBMS_ERROR_TEXT returns the entire sequence of recursive errors

so you should get all the required information from that

Kindly use

```
exception when others then functionThatPrintsMe(DBMS_ERROR_TEXT);
```

for more information about oracle 6i forms you can refer

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/documentation/6i-forms-084462.html

Comment: This does not give me the name of the program unit where the error is triggered; We currently use the one you say :S

Comment: Do you know the block from which the initial package or the PLL is getting called??

Comment: Yes, I know the initial call; it is triggered by a control button. And navigates through (for about) 10 packages which can have many function and procedures.

Comment: using the debugger you can try to figure out the error source,Kindly refer this link for the same 
https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=666660

Comment: Go to the control button and set the breakpoint to the initial package and then use step into the package,now use step over for each called function and if it fails in one of them use Step into and follow the same Approach,i hope this will atleast be helpful to you

Answer (score 1):

At form level ON-ERROR TRIGGER .Add these lines will solve your problem

```
--form level error display

message(ERROR_type||'-'||TO_CHAR(message_code)||': '||ERROR_text); message(' ');

--Database level error display

    if DBMS_ERROR_TEXT is not null then 
            message(DBMS_ERROR_TEXT );message(' ');     
   end if ;
```